# TransactionScope and Ajax call returning error response

Tags: ajax, entity-framework, model-view-controller, transactionscope

I have an Ajax call which calls a particular method.

```
$.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("ExcelDataUpload", "ProjectDefinition")',
    type: "POST",
    headers: { "cache-control": "no-cache" },
    //data: { XLTransactionType: xltranstype, FilePath: filepath },
    data: { XLTransactionType: xltranstype, ExcelUploadData: exceljsonData },
    cache: false,
    success: function (data) {
        if (data != null && data.StatusID == 1) {
            ShowMessage(1, data.Message);                   
        }
        else {
            ShowMessage(0, data.Message);
        }
    },
    error: function (data) {
        ShowMessage(0, "Upload is not successful.Please try again!!!");
    }
});
```

Inside this method operation is performed using transaction scope

```
using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.RequiresNew, TimeSpan.FromHours(1))) { 
    try { 
        using (objDb = new UPDEntities()) { } 
    } 

    if(id > 0) { 
        scope.Complete(); 
    } else { 
        scope.Dispose(); 
    }
}
```

This takes 3-4 minutes to complete but before Ajax call completes it always returns error message and if data is less it returns success. How do I pause Ajax call till transaction scope completes its operation?

Answer (score 0):

jquery Ajax async true works by default.

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

use async false to wait for a response, I think it's more accurate to use signalR

Comment: I have used that also but no use. Getting same error exactly after 1 minute.

Comment: @user10476550 use signalR, it is not right to keep the client waiting on server-side long processes like this